# Multiplicative strictly increasing sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $1=x_1<x_2<x_3<\cdots$ is a strictly increasing sequence such that $x_{nm}=x_n x_m$ for all $n,m$. Is it true that there has to exist some $c>0$ such that $x_n=n^c$?

Comment: This has the flavor of an olympiad problem.  Can you give the reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is indeed the case. We know that $x_{1} = 1$. Suppose that $x_{2} = 2^{c}$ for some $c > 0$.

$\textbf{Claim:}$ $$x_{n} = x_{n-1}^{\frac{1}{\log_{n}(n-1)}}$$

For $n \geq 3$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ We know that for each $m \geq 1$ we have $n^{\log_{n}((n-1)^m)} = (n-1)^m$. Thus

$$x_{n^{\lfloor\log_{n}((n-1)^m)}\rfloor} < x_{(n-1)^m} < x_{n^{\lceil\log_{n}((n-1)^m)}\rceil}.$$

Thus

$$(x_{n})^{\lfloor\log_{n}((n-1)^m)\rfloor} < (x_{n-1})^m < (x_{n})^{\lceil\log_{n}((n-1)^m)\rceil}$$

In particular the expression

$$(\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n}^{\log_{n}(n-1)}})^m$$

is bounded as $m$ varies over $\mathbb{N}$. This is possible only if

$$x_{n}^{\log_{n}(n-1)} = x_{n-1}.$$

Now suppose that $x_{j} = j^{c}$ for $j=1,...n-1$. Note that $$x_{n} = (n-1)^{c\frac{1}{\log_{n}(n-1)}}$$

$$= e^{\log(n-1)\frac{c \log(n)}{\log(n-1)}}$$

$$= n^c.$$

Thus the proof follows by induction.